# How to use PayPal V2 in PHP to create an order?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement PayPal API for creating orders but I'm having a hard time understanding V2 from V1 and how to run the code since the Sandbox uses JSON and I'm using cURL converted to PHP.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

**[This is a picture of my PayPal Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bv7B.png) You can see that after I hit "Send" I get results in the bottom window which generates the links including the "approve" link which takes the customer to the checkout page to pay.**

So how do I echo out this specific link?

I tried doing like

```
$letssee = $response['data']['approve'];

echo "<a href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";
```

or

```
$letssee = $response['links']['approve'];

echo "<a href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";
```

````css
```php

<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
  array (
  "intent" => "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units" => 
    array (
      "amount" =>
      array (
        "currency_code" => "USD",
        "value" => "100.00"
      )
    )
  )
));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($response);

$letssee = $response['data']['links'][0];

echo "<a class="lel" href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";

?>

```
````

**EDIT** When I format the postfields like so, I get all results but I still cant get the specific link.

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\n  \"intent\": \"CAPTURE\",\n\n  \"purchase_units\": [\n\n    {\n\n      \"amount\": {\n\n        \"currency_code\": \"USD\",\n\n        \"value\": \"100.00\"\n\n      }\n\n    }\n\n  ]\n\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($response);

$letssee = $response['data']['links'][0];

echo "<a class='lel' href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";

?>
```

The result..

```
Array ( [id] => 7T223580KS69XXXX [status] => CREATED [links] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/7T223580KS69XXXX [rel] => self [method] => GET ) [1] => Array ( [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=7T223580KS69XXXX [rel] => approve [method] => GET ) [2] => Array ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/7T223580KS69XXXX [rel] => update [method] => PATCH ) [3] => Array ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/7T223580KS69XXXX/capture [rel] => capture [method] => POST ) ) )
```

The link I'm trying to get: `[1] => Array ( [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=7T223580KS69XXXX`

Comment: i don't think your links has any property called "approve", plus the key "links" is an array. i would try something like `$letssee = $response['data']['links'][0]`.  You should probably use print_r() and post the  structure of the response.

Comment: @chidimez Hi, when I use print_r() I get `Array ( [name] => INVALID_REQUEST [message] => Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema. [debug_id] => b660cf44ac36b [details] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [field] => /purchase_units [location] => body [issue] => MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON [description] => The request JSON is not well formed. ) ) [links] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [href] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON [rel] => information_link [encType] => application/json ) ) ) `

Answer (score 0):

> Array ( [name] => INVALID_REQUEST [message] => Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema. [debug_id] => b660cf44ac36b [details] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [field] => /purchase_units [location] => body [issue] => MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON [description] => The request JSON is not well formed. ) ) [links] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [href] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON [rel] => information_link [encType] => application/json ) ) )

This error is occuring because purchase_units in the request must be an *indexed* array, the zeroeth element of which then contains a JSON object (an associative array in php)

So, something like this (not tested):

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
  array (
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => array (
      array(
        "amount" => array (
          "currency_code" => "USD",
          "value" => "100.00"
        )
      )
    )
  )
));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but the issue was caused by the arrays/the way it was structured, I just tried your code and get the same error but I have updated my question and am successfully creating the checkout token link now, I just need to get the link into the `<a>` tag do you know how?

Comment: You should create two routes that return JSON and use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server instead

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I managed to get your code working and it is displaying the information including the links but how do I get the one specific link? I am trying like this `$letssee = $response['data']['links'][1]; echo "<a class='leggo' href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";`

Comment: Don't use any redirects or links. That is an old integration pattern, for old websites. Use the JS SDK for payer approval.

Comment: Ah okay, I see, why do they make it so confusing lmao, I thought the V2 docs were the most relevant/recent but this SDK version works a lot nicer and seems very simple, does this only require the 'client_id' token? do you know if there are any other docs for this type of integration? Thanks again

Comment: You misunderstand, the v2 API can still be used to create and capture the order from your PHP backend, which is the most robust solution

Comment: If you use the JS SDK all by itself (client-side integration only that doesn't call routes on your server) it's certainly simple, but not robust.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\n  \"intent\": \"CAPTURE\",\n\n  \"purchase_units\": [\n\n    {\n\n      \"amount\": {\n\n        \"currency_code\": \"USD\",\n\n        \"value\": \"100.00\"\n\n      }\n\n    }\n\n  ]\n\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($response);

$letssee = $response['data']['links'][11,002.93[https://www.paypal.com/invoice/p/#44L6UCQ45BS7KLNS

> ``

][1];

echo "<a class='lel' href='$letssee'>Pay Now!</a>";

?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).